# Get Azure Batch ResourceFile from existing file in Azure Blob Container

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I am following this tutorial to do my first steps with Azure Batch

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/BatchDotnetTutorialFfmpeg/Program.cs

There is one method to upload files to a container and to get back a ResourceFile for further processing.

```
private static ResourceFile UploadFileToContainer(CloudBlobClient blobClient, string containerName, string filePath)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading file {0} to container [{1}]...", filePath, containerName);

        string blobName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filePath);

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blobData = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        blobData.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath).Wait();

        // Set the expiry time and permissions for the blob shared access signature. 
        // In this case, no start time is specified, so the shared access signature 
        // becomes valid immediately
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        };

        // Construct the SAS URL for blob
        string sasBlobToken = blobData.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
        string blobSasUri = String.Format("{0}{1}", blobData.Uri, sasBlobToken);

        return ResourceFile.FromUrl(blobSasUri, filePath); 
}
```

This works fine as long as you want to upload your files again and again. For some reason my upload broke down and I did not get the ResourceFile Object.

So how can I get a ResourceFile Object from an already uploaded file to an existing container?

Regards

Michael

Comment: Do you know the name/URL of the resource file?

Comment: @GauravMantri well, I could get a list of all already uploaded files to the container.